# Why are some pandas aggregation functions in quotes and others not?

Tags: pandas

I have a line of code in a colleague's module which works, but which I do not understand:

```python
grouped_frame = frame.groupby(['user_id']).agg({'total': ['first', list]})['total'].reset_index()
```

If I replace `'first'` with `first` I get the error

> NameError: name 'first' is not defined

If I replace `list` with `'list'` I get the error

> AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'list'

Why does `'first`' need to be in quotes and `list` need to not be?

Comment: list is a reserved python keyword whereas first is not, it is an aggregation function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890498/pandas-apply-difference-if-function-name-is-in-quotes-or-not/69725116#69725116)

in short:
`'first'` (with quotes) means, `agg()` will search for a function named `first` belonging to a `pd.Series`, i.e. `pd.Series.first()`
`list` (without quote) means, `agg()` will search for a function named `list` in default python.

Python has `list()` built-in, python has no such function called `first()`